# Powershell -Get ADComputer

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to display CPU details like core count and processor name using the  Get -ADComputer command?

or do i use another command to do the same, what im using now

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {enabled -eq $true} -properties *|select Name, 
DNSHostName, OperatingSystem, LastLogonDate
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: HW specs are not stored in AD. Not relevant for authentication. Check different WMI-classes using `Get-WMIObject`. Ex. Win32_Processor

Answer (score 0):

There are environment variables available to give you processor information:

## Code

```
Write-Output "PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE = $env:PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE"
Write-Output "PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER   = $env:PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER"
Write-Output "PROCESSOR_LEVEL        = $env:PROCESSOR_LEVEL"
Write-Output "PROCESSOR_REVISION     = $env:PROCESSOR_REVISION"
Write-Output "NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS   = $env:NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS"
```

## Example Result

[image: Example results]

Comment: so how do i put that on the script im using? so i need to write two scripts?

Comment: @CarlHussain your original question/requirement is not clear enough at present to answer your followup question.

Comment: I want to list all computers on the domain, while displaying cpu info and login name of the user

Comment: As @Frode F already wrote these information are not stored in the AD. You would have to reach every single computer and get the information from there,